# Are there Plugin Compatibility Issues between QGIS 1.6.0 and 1.7.4?

Tags: python, qgis, qgis-plugins

I've been working on a QGIS plugin on Quantum GIS 1.6.0 Copiapo with Python 2.5 that calculates additional values for eachf feature of a vector layer and adds them to the .dbf. We've just upgraded to QGIS 1.7.4 Wroclaw with Python 2.7. But since the upgrade the plugin doesn't work anymore in 1.7.4.
While on 1.6.0 all functionalities work fine, running the plugin in 1.7.4 actions on a number of QPushButtons and some other functionality within the ui do not trigger any actions. I've tried both the old and the new-style connections, like:

```
QObject.connect(browseCalcButton, SIGNAL('clicked ()'), self.browseCalcFunction)

browseCalcButton.clicked.connect(self.browseCalcFunction)
```

This seems to be true for all QPushButtons that DON'T either call...

- ... a handler: 
  attributesButtons[i].clicked.connect(self.createHandler_assign_attribute(i, key))
- ... an existing pyqt method: 
  eA_Fertigstellen.clicked.connect(self.eAui.hide)

... but rather a function within the script:

- browseCalcButton.clicked.connect(self.browseCalc)

Are there compatibility issues between QGIS 1.6.0 and 1.7.4?
Are there any adjustments neccessary?

Has anyone had similar problems?

Comment: You likely hit a difference in Qt version. I believe this was mentioned on the QGIS developer mailing list.